# ESP32 - fs.open is slower as filename increments

Tags: arduino, esp32, sd-card

ESP32 using VScode platformio.
Adafruit sd card module connected using spi and standard SD library for ESP32.
I have files stored on SD card and they are named as follows:

1, 2, 3, ... 253, 254.

All files are 3kb in size and contain ascii characters, and alternate files are exact copies.

I noticed that as the code continued to open and close files for reading (Starting from 1, incrementing by 1, finishing at 254), the output to my RGB display was becoming slower and slower.

I pinpointed the exact cause by measuring the time taken to execute some lines for file 1 and file 254. This line was causing the issue:

```
for (byte x=1; x<=254; x++) { // Iterate for all images on sd card
      fname = "/" + String(x); // Form image file name
      unsigned long t1 = millis();
      image = fs.open(fname, FILE_READ); //LINE CAUSING DELAY
      unsigned long t2 = millis();
      unsigned long time = (t2-t1);
      Serial.println("Time = " + (String) time);
```

Where fname is a number ranging from 1 - 254. It seems as the number increases it takes longer to open the file:

Time for file 254 = 74ms
Time for file 1 = 1ms

The time decreases in a uniform maner as file goes to 1. It is not caused by the filename length (ie. 254 is 3 digit, 1 is 1 digit), file 101 had a proportionate increase in open time than file 200, they were not the same.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening? It is a crucial issue in my code as the output needs to be at a constant speed and not decrease as the file increments.

Comment: Do you need to close the file after opening it? Can you verify by adding some print outs that the file sizes are actually the same at runtime?

Comment: I assume file needs closing before opening another? But the delay is caused solely by the fs.open line. I can confirm the file sizes are exactly the same. I ran a test where I reversed the naming structure of the files (so 1 is now 254, 2 is 253 etc), and the speed of fs.open still decreased as before, so the issue isn't caused by the files themselves

Comment: I have been able to narrow the timing down. Starting from 1, the time increases 4-5ms every 14-15 increments in file name. Not caused by length of file name

Comment: Asking again what @vicatcu asked - are you closing the files? You didn't actually answer that. Your code doesn't show you closing them. You need to do an explicit call to `image.close()` to close each file. If you're not closing them, try doing that.

Comment: Yes I am closing the files, it's a bit further down in the code after data has been read

Comment: That is simply the time needed for the flash to search for and open your file. Try working with offsets or some other reference to your data, so that you can save a costly filename lookup. If you can't, atleast move your function to IRAM using IRAM_ATTR, so the code doesnt need to be reloaded from flash after every file.